# How to show current year in .vue project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, pug

I have been working on a project and I am stuck here.

I am using Jade template at .vue  and i need to show current year but I have not been able to do it

```
<template lang='jade'>
// Footer
footer#footer.footer
.container
  .row
.footer-wrapper
      .col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
        .footer-brand
img(src='assets/images/logo-white.png', alt='logo')
      .col-md-6.col-sm-6.col-xs-12
.copyright
          p
 a(href='https://www.easycryptocoins.info/')  Easycryptos
            script.
© 2018 - {{ new Date().getFullYear() }}
| . All rights reserved.
  </template> 

          `
```

I expect to get in copyright 2018 -(current year) but i am only gettin' Easycryptos

Comment: It's nice if you use a state variable and then make reference to it

Comment: Try using either a [computed property](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) or [data](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Data-and-Methods) to store the variable

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to create a property called 'currentDate' in your data object and use it in your template like:

```
data(){
     return {
        currentDate: new Date,
        }
 }
```

and in your template do it like :

```
 {{currentDate.getFullYear()}}
```

You should instantiate an object in order to access its methods.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to be lazy, you can also just do the whole thing inline, though it's not the best practice.

```
{{ new Date().getFullYear() }}
```